# Switching off services in iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm using monotouch to develop an application and part of it requires me to be able to switch off the likes of the internet and texting. I've searched through the documents and can't seem to find how to do it without the user being asked (that part is important).

I can do it simply enough with Android, but not with iOS.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Apple does not expose APIs to do this without prompting the user.

Comment: This is correct. Only Jailbroken iOS devices can do that but i do not recommend to do that nor support people who does that.

Comment: You have to prompt the user to do it themselves